# Excel formula doesn't work well if additional if statement is added to current formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble adding one more condition to excel formula. The current formula is working well, but adding one more condition gives wrong data.

Current formula

```
=IF(D8=1,D11+D13+C14,IF(D7=1,C14+(D11+D13), C14))
```

Results are shown in D14 cell. After I got result from the formula above, I need to check result. 
If the result is lower than 0.5 I should print 0.5. I can get for ex. -2.4, that should print 0.5 as a result.

Any Idea would help.

Comment: `C14 + (D11 + D13)` in the inner `IF` is equivalent to `D11 + D13 + C14` in the outer `IF`, so it seems like the formula could be simplified. Can you share some sample data and what the result should be?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print 0.5 if the value is lower than 0.5, you can use `MAX` function, which takes the greater between 0.5 and D14.

```
=MAX(0.5,D14)
```